# Como remover o separador decimal de um resultado?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Na consulta sql eu tenho um valor total do pedido multiplicado por 1000:

Valor total: 195.41
Valor Visualizado : 195410.00

Como eu poderia remover o separador?

SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(195410.00 AS money), 0) AS varchar)

Comment: Multiplicando por 100?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Conforme comentado pelo @Maniero, é só multiplicar o valor por 100 ao invés de 1000.

Caso você não possua gerência sobre essa multiplicação, a conversão para INT sugerida pelo @PabloVargas também é válida, desde que o valor não seja superior ao admitido pelo campo (-2^31 (-2.147.483.648) a 2^31-1 (2.147.483.647) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187745.aspx)

Conversão para INT:

```
SELECT CAST(195410.00 AS INT)
```

Também é possível simplesmente suprimir os caracteres após o ponto:

```
select LEFT(195410.00, CHARINDEX('.', 195410.00) - 1)
```

Comment: valeu deu certo ! amigo

Comment: Legal. Só dá um ok na resposta. Tks

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um `convert` para `int`, veja como fica

```
declare @valor_total decimal(18,2) = 195.41

select convert(int, @valor_total*1000)
```

Comment: Muito bom, era isso mesmo